# BUILD FAILED test.xml:7: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, eclipse

I don't get what is wrong here
   I closed all tabs
it freak me out

and I allsow not shore if I have the god bat path should it be this file pat or an empty file path I am a beginner in java and I am doing by the book and book is old and not to good in explication

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<project name="Run Test" default="run_test" basedir=".">
<property name="test.dir" value="src\test" />
<property name="testLibDir" value="lib" />
</project>

    <target name="start-server">
        <java jar="lib/selenium-server.jar"
            fork="true" spawn="true">
        </java>
    </target>
<target name="stop-server">
    <get taskname="selenium-shutdown"
        src="http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer"
        dest="result.txt" ignoreerrors="true" />
            <echo taskname="selenium-shutdown" message="DGF Errors during shutdown are expected"/>
</target>

<target name="run_test" description="Start Proxy ; Run Test ; stop Proxy">
    <parallel>
        <antcall target="start-server">
        </antcall>
            <sequential>
                <echo taskname="waitfor" message="Wait for proxy server launch" />
                <waitfor maxwait="2" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="100">
                    <http url="http://localhost:4444/seleniumserver/driver/?cmd=testComplete"/>
                </waitfor>
                    <antcall target="run_test">
                    </antcall>
                <antcall target="stop-server">
                </antcall>
            </sequential>
    </parallel>
</target>
<schedule>
    <ant antscript="D:\Automation\eclipse\Workspace2\testing.bat"
            antworkingdir="D:\Automation\eclipse\Workspace2\Test2"
            buildfile="build.xml"
            uselogger="true"
            usedebug="false"/>
</schedule>
   </project>
```

edited

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: you have no [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). Every XML file requires a [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), otherwise the markup isn't valid!

Comment: well I try set <parrent> </parrent> in front of <target> end on the end but error don't disapear

Comment: @Dima: You should use the `project` tag as root element. Add `<project>` under the `<?xml ... ?>` line and add `</project>` at the bottom of your file.

Comment: "+1" eap thet solve it thx a lot but now the same error on row 25     <code><echo taskname="waitfor"message="Wait for proxy server launch" />'

Comment: @Dima: I'm sorry, but I've no idea what's wrong with that. That line looks well-formed to me.

Comment: to me to tnx any way hellped much

Comment: @Dima: I found the error: add a space between `taskname="waitfor"` and `message=` and also add a space between `maxwaitunit="minute"` and `checkevery="100"`

Comment: done and now appears BUILD FAILED
D:\Automation\eclipse\Workspace2\Test\test.xml:3: Problem: failed to create task or type project
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: @Dima: I can't help you with that because that has no longer to do with syntax errors in XML. I'm not a Java programmer, so unfortunately I've no idea how to fix that problem.

Comment: @Dima: Your XML file is well-formed now, but about the latest error that you got, I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `</project>` closing tag should be placed at the end of the document.

Comment: thx the error disappear now appear other Error: Main method not found in class Testare, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @Dima: You have to create a main method. More info: [The Java Main Method](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html)